# add one row from another dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here's the thing, I need to put one row from other dataframe to the top of main dataframe in pandas, above first row where are columns named.

Sample :

```
       1value  2value 3value 4value 5value
acity    4       3       6      2     6
bcity    2       6       6      4     1
ccity    5       11      53     6     3
dcity    5       1       4      6     3 
gcity    6       4       2      7     4
```

And the other sample:

```
1value 2value 3value 4value 5value
 2       5       2      6     3
```

And now I need to add value of second sample to the top of first sample. Desired output:

```
         2       5       2      6     3 
      1value  2value 3value 4value 5value
acity    4       3       6      2     6
bcity    2       6       6      4     1
ccity    5       11      53     6     3
dcity    5       1       4      6     3 
gcity    6       4       2      7     4
```

And just for mention, I have about 3000 rows, and 250 columns in this Sample dataframe.

I don't have any code yet, I tried to find here something...

Comment: Are you looking for a multi-index column data frame?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean, I'm a beginner, but here it is. Values from second sample(that is dataframe too) are reference values and that's the reason why that should be above the first row, where are names of columns. @Psidom

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you need, but a multi index data frame looks like the output:

*df1 or second sample*:

[image]

*df or the first sample*:

[image]

Rename the columns with a multi-index columns:

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df1.values[0], df.columns])
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah, that's it, but I just have problem called :
unhashable type: 'dict'

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. Are the two samples both data frames?

Comment: Yes, both are data frames. 
Type of both is 
pandas.core.frame.DataFrame

Comment: You might have some issues somewhere else. I can't think of a way this can cause a `unhashable` error.

Comment: Okey, thank you anyway, this code is what I have look for. :)